# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function getOptions() on a non-object

Tags: magento-1.9, php, fatal-error, ce-1.9.2.4, m2epro

I get this message:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getOptions() on a
>   non-object in /M2ePro/Model/Amazon/Listing/Product.php on line 299.

The code on line 299 is:

```
 $options    = $variation->getOptions(true);
```

How to solve?

Comment: You'll need to take this up with M2E, as they have their own support forum and choose not to participate here.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that $variation is, erm... without wanting to sound rude, not an object.  Whilst there should be some error checking around it

```
if(is_object($variation){
    $options    = $variation->getOptions(true);
}
```

it looks like that something that is expected by the module has not be loaded or configured correctly.

Checking the code from [Github](https://github.com/m2epro/magento-extension/blob/master/app/code/community/Ess/M2ePro/Model/Amazon/Listing/Product.php) I would start to look at solving the problem at the point on line 299 starting with (from line 286):

```
    public function getActualMagentoProduct()
{
    if (!$this->getVariationManager()->isPhysicalUnit() ||
        !$this->getVariationManager()->getTypeModel()->isVariationProductMatched()
    ) {
        return $this->getMagentoProduct();
    }
    if ($this->getMagentoProduct()->isConfigurableType() ||
        $this->getMagentoProduct()->isGroupedType()) {
        $variations = $this->getVariations(true);
        $variation  = reset($variations);
        $options    = $variation->getOptions(true);
        $option     = reset($options);
        return $option->getMagentoProduct();
    }
    return $this->getMagentoProduct();
}
```

becoming:

```
    public function getActualMagentoProduct()
{
    if (!$this->getVariationManager()->isPhysicalUnit() ||
        !$this->getVariationManager()->getTypeModel()->isVariationProductMatched()
    ) {
        return $this->getMagentoProduct();
    }
    if ($this->getMagentoProduct()->isConfigurableType() ||
        $this->getMagentoProduct()->isGroupedType()) {
        $variations = $this->getVariations(true);
        $variation  = reset($variations);
        //changes here
        if(is_object($variation)){
         $options    = $variation->getOptions(true);
        }else{
         $options    = array();
        }
        //to here
        $option     = reset($options);
        return $option->getMagentoProduct();
    }
    return $this->getMagentoProduct();
}
```

Now I don't actually know this module so, if you are not a coder you might want to seek support from the module developers.

It does seem like you have a product variation configured (perhaps colour) but one without any options (perhaps red, blue, white). That is just an educated guess though.

Comment: What have I to modify?

Comment: have updated my answer - may help